# Javascript cannot change style in css file?

Tags: javascript, css

Recently I made a archive box for my blog. Firstly I use style attribute for styling my  list. But when I moved the css code in style attribute to a separate css file, my JS code didn't work. The following codes work fine when click the -> button.

[image: the code that works fine]

But when I use class of css instead of style attribute, the JS code doesnt't work. I cannot see the sub list items on the screen when I click the -> button. So I don't want to use style attribute. Because it easy to read style code from css file in my website. What can I do for handling this problem? Any suggestion?

[image: the code that doesn't work]

Note: Because "insert into post" button in code snippet tool doesn't work, I put codes as images into my post.

Comment: You should include a link to your jsfiddle next time, instead of pasting screenshots of jsfiddles.

Comment: Djd you try the technique called "debugging"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're checking the style attribute, which you're not setting anymore. Just assume that the thing is not visible when you don't see a value since that's the default.

```
if (!months.style.display || months.style.display == "none") {
   months.style.display = "block";
}
```

After the first click the style attribute will have a value and it should work.